# iOS WebView: open single hyperlink in external browser

Tags: html, ios, css, hyperlink

There's a simple UIWebView in my iOS app. Hyperlinks open normally in my app itself. But there's a single hyperlink I want to open in external standard browser (Safari).

I image something `like <a href="http://example.com" target="_safari">`.

Is there anything like this?

**I'm not able to make changes in the app itself. I have to do that on my website!**

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `UIWebViewDelegate` method for achieving that. Implement following method of the delegate

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    let urlStr = request.url?.absoluteString
    if //urlStr is string you want {
         //launch external browser
         return false
    }
    return true
}
```

This method will be called every time you try to load a url in web view. You can compare if its URL you want to load, if it matches then launch external browser and return false.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention: I'm not able to make changes in the app itself. I have to do that on my website!

Answer (score -2):

try this way

```
<a onclick="window.open('https://www.google.co.in/', '_system');" href="#">Google</a>
```

Comment: One quote is missing, I guess: `<a onclick="window.open('https://www.google.co.in/', '_system');" href="#">Google</a>`. But still opening in the app itself.